# Checking equality within an javascript array

Tags: javascript, for-loop

I'm stuck on this CodeWars problem where I check to see if a letter is repeated within a word and I'm having a problem checking for equality. The letters appear to be all strictly not equal as the loop iterates.

```
function isIsogram(str){
  var split = str.toLowerCase().split('');
  var result = true;

  for (var i = 0; i < str.length; i++){
    for (var j = i+1; j < str.length; j++){
      if (split[i] !== split[i][j]) {
          console.log(split[i]+ " -> "+ split[j] );
        } 
        else {
           console.log("They are equal");
        }            
      }
    }
 }
isIsogram( "abca" )
```

Comment: What is `split[i][j]` supposed to be? `split` is not a 2-dimensional array.

Comment: That should just be `split[j]`. BTW, there's no need to convert the string to an array, since you can access string elements with `str[i]`.

Comment: FYI you can achieve this with a regular expression `'abcba'.match(/([\s\S])(?=[\s\S]*?\1)/g); // ["a", "b"]`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Comparing `split[i]` to `split[i][j]`, but logging `split[j]` to console instead. Do you want compare it to `split[j]` instead?

This looks more intuitive:

```
function isIsogram(str){
    var str2 = str.toLowerCase();
    var result = true;

    for (var i = 0; i < str2.length; i++){
        for (var j = i+1; j < str2.length; j++){
            if (str2[i] !== str2[j]) {
                console.log(str2[i]+ " -> "+ str2[j] );
            } 
            else {
                console.log("They are equal");
            }            
        }
    }
}
isIsogram( "abca" )
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! This is really a comment, not an answer. With a bit more rep, [you will be able to post comments](//stackoverflow.com/privileges/comment). For the moment I've added the comment for you, and I'm flagging this post for deletion.